# Is this logo too asymmetrical or does it matter?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, logo, typography, design-principles, lettering

I'm designing a logo for a startup called “peak development” that requires some sort of mountain peak in the title.

I'm happy enough with the concept, basically the A is the peak, but one option has the A at a regular size, the other has it noticeably taller than the other letters, to stand out as a peak.

I'm not sure if the first option is unclear that the A is a peak, and also unsure if the second option is asymmetrical and unnecessary (having the A taller).

Any opinions welcome :)[image: two logo options]

Comment: It's *exceptionally* difficult to judge symmetry with the gradient fill. Your opposing gradients make the left image appear weak on its right side, and the right image appear weak on its left side. Logo development may be best as 1 color until the forms are solidified.

Comment: gradients can also be problematic when printing, but that is covered in many questions on this site

Comment: Orienting the gradient vertically instead of horizontally may be a better connection with the idea ‘peak development’. That idea conveys movement towards excellence which is implied to be ongoing. Since we have a ‘peak’ representing that excellence then the movement of the development if upward.
So keep the gradient if you like it.
With this minor alteration you will avoid the symmetrical balance problem. Just make sure it’s print-friendly in the final color configuration. Perhaps the colors could be a bit closer on the spectrum but without becoming monochromatic.
Best of luck.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I like part of each concept and dislike part of each concept. So looking at both:

- In design A (on the left) I like how "PEAK" is resolved. However, I do not like the condensed treatment of "DEVELOPMENT".
- In design B (on the right) I don't care for the oversized 'peaked' letter A. It monopolizes the focus and keeps me from 'seeing' all of the elements as one entity, all at once so to say. But, I do like this design's treatment of "DEVELOPMENT" with the exception of removing the font's italic case using regular or book case.

So in summary, unite the top left 'PEAK' with an unitalicized bottom right 'DEVELOPMENT' to create your brand mark. Welcome to design C! This revision, will now present a palatable and pleasing difference in the cap heights of the two words. In design A, it feels like 'DEVELOPMENT' is trying to stretch upward to equal "PEAK", creating a distracting tension between the two words.

Color? I favor the coloring in design B, but not enough to require it.

I hope this helped. You have a nice start underway.